# How to update Puppeteer's Chromium?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a problem with chromium when I run my tests through the puppeteer.

What happens is that my tests require the microphone to be enabled the moment I log in to the application, even after adding:

`'--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] : ['--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'`

Before working normally, after changing the machine it stopped working and I don't know if it is related to the version of the chromium that is started:

This is the version of chromium when testing starts:

Version 77.0.3844.0

[image]

And my version of the puppeteer is:

```"puppeteer": "^1.19.0"````

Has anyone ever experienced this? If so, how do I update the chromium?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if your current issue is related to the Chromium version but the current stable version is 9.0.0 which has a bundled Chromium 91.0.4469.0 (r869685). You just need to update puppeteer with `yarn add puppeteer` or `npm i puppeteer`

Comment: I executed the command mentioned above, but my chromium has not updated. 
I didn't understand the behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see there is a caret(^) in your package.json (sorry that line has a bit tricky readability). So, if you want a new Chromium you need to upgrade to a newer Puppeteer. 9.x.x is the latest at the moment. Because of the `^` in the version you can only upgrade to  <2.0.0 with `npm i`.
Make sure you upgrade to the latest Puppeteer version, then you will have the latest (bundled) Chromium. Example can be checked here: https://flaviocopes.com/update-npm-dependencies/